# WebAPI 2 - CORS not working with contentType application/json

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I've got an Asp.net WebApi 2 project, with a `Booking` controller

If I try to post this from my client-side js:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:57517/api/booking',
            type: 'POST',
            crossDomain:true,
            data: {AdultPaxCount:1},
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
```

I get a not-allowed error (and the `Post` action on my `BookingController` is not hit)

However;

If I remove the

> contentType: "application/json"

section, it 'works' (it is sent to the controller)

Am I missing something in my setup?

Comment: do you use IE 8 (or less) ?

Comment: no, this was from Chrome

Comment: You can probably check if this tutorial helps you: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add an Options method to your controller which always just returns without error, or add the

```
[HttpOptions]
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "OPTIONS")]
```

attributes to the PostXXX Method of your controller.

Answer (score 3):

With that content-type, the browser will preflight the request.  This means that the browser will send an OPTIONS request initially, and will only send the underlying request if your server responds appropriately to the preflight.  So, the error is caused by your server rejecting the preflight (OPTIONS) request.  You will either need to handle the preflight request server-side, or ensure the browser does not preflight the request by only sending a "simple" cross-origin request.  More in the [preflighting section of the MDN article on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Answer (score 2):

The only **Content-type** values that won’t trigger a CORS preflight request are **text/plain**, **multipart/form-data**, **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.